# Define an inherited column to be part of composite primary key in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have an abstract base entity class that defines columns found in all of our entities (e.g. creation and modifications timestamps and related user IDs). For most of our entities, there are two related database tables: one that holds the "live" data, i.e. the current state of the entity; and one that holds the audit trail, i.e. all historical versions of the entity, as snapshots.

One of the columns shared by all entities (and defined in the base entity class) is a version number column, which is a simple running sequence that tells how many edits have been made to that particular entity. The version column is present in both the audit table and the "regular" table, but in the audit table, the version column is also part of a composite primary key, which is formed by combining the primary key of the "regular" entity and the version number. Simplified example (some entity-level annotations omitted for brevity):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;

    // Timestamps, user IDs etc.
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class PersonBase extends BaseEntity {
    // All basic columns of a person defined here
}

public class Person extends PersonBase {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    // All references to other entities defined here
}

public class PersonAudit extends PersonBase {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    // FIXME: Version column should be part of composite primary key

    // All foreign key columns defined here (can't have 
    // a direct FK relationship in an audit table, as you 
    // don't know which version to link to)
}
```

**Is it possible to make the inherited version column be part of a composite primary key in the audit entities?** I tried declaring the version column also in the `PersonAudit` table and adding the `@Id` annotation to it, but after that the version field in `BaseEntity` wasn't populated anymore. It'd be very convenient to have the field in `BaseEntity` as we use it in some generic Criteria Queries using the JPA static metamodel, and if we move the field declaration to the individual audit entities, we can't reference the column anymore in those queries.

P.S. We're using Hibernate, so Hibernate-specific solutions are also acceptable if JPA doesn't enable this.

Comment: Why do you want it to be part of the PK? You have a unique ID already as a PK.

Comment: The original primary key of the Person table is not unique in the audit table, as you have multiple rows representing the same person there. You need to include the version number to make it unique.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Both the Person and PersonAudit tables have `@Id` annotations, thus they both must be unique PKs.

Comment: Yeah, but the mapping in PersonAudit is incomplete. As the comment mentions, the auditSequence column should be part of the composite primary key. PersonAudit can't have the same primary key as Person, as the audit table will contain multiple snapshots of the same person, all having the same value in the id column. Thus the id column alone is not unique.